# bitwise shift right with long not equaling zero?

Tags: scala

I was playing in the REPL, and I see this behavior for `>>` and `>>>`. It seems that a Long should occupy 64 bits, so shifting right by `64` should always zero out the number.

```
scala> 64 >> 64
res22: Int = 64

scala> 64 >> 65
res23: Int = 32

scala> 64 >> 66
res24: Int = 16

scala> 64 >> 67
res25: Int = 8

scala> 64 >> 68
res26: Int = 4

scala> 64 >> 69
res27: Int = 2

scala> 64 >> 70
res28: Int = 1

scala> 64 >> 71
res29: Int = 0

scala> 64 >>> 64
res30: Int = 64

scala> 64 >>> 65
res31: Int = 32
```

What is this behavior in Scala?

Comment: You ask about `Long` values, but your examples use `Int`. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: It appears that the behavior is the same regardless? I'm using scala 2.11.7 fwiw

Comment: Its same anyway `scala> 64l >> 64l = 64`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala takes the right hand and applies it modulo the word size of the left hand operand. You will get the same result for `Int` using right hand values of 32, 64 and 128.

```
scala> 64 >> 64
res0: Int = 64

scala> 64 >> 1
res1: Int = 32

scala> 64 >> 32
res2: Int = 64

scala> 8 >> 32
res3: Int = 8

scala> 8 >> 64
res4: Int = 8

scala> 8 >> 128
res5: Int = 8

scala> 64L >> 64
res6: Long = 64

scala> 64L >> 32
res7: Long = 0
```

Comment: Hmm, is this unique to Scala or the same behavior in Java as well? I didn't know this

Comment: @ChrisStewart Java is the same.  I feel like there's a good chance that the Scala version is just using the Java functionality, but I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

binary for `64` is `1000000`,

you have to right shift by (7 to 31) to get 0.

```
scala> import java.lang.Long
import java.lang.Long

scala> Long.toBinaryString(64)
res139: String = 1000000

scala> Long.toBinaryString(64 >> 6 )
res140: String = 1

scala> Long.toBinaryString(64 >> 7 )
res141: String = 0
```

31+ will give you the same result,

```
scala> 64 >> 64
res1: Int = 64

scala> 64 >> 32
res2: Int = 64

scala> 64 >> 128
res3: Int = 64
```

Same in `java.lang.Long` or `scala.Long`